# Is maximum likelihood a method for estimating parameters or estimating a distribution?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I am narrowing down on some more solid idea of what MLE is, and what we use it for.

I keep running across different perspectives from different sources.

Some places, I read that maximum likelihood is a method for estimating parameters of a distribution, given we have some data.

Other places, I read that the maximum likelihood is itself a distribution.

What do we get from this process?  A set of parameters for a distribution we already are trying to fit?  Or do we get a 'new' distribution at the end of the process?  Or both?

Comment: The  key is that the E in MLE means estimation. So, MLE is estimating parameters and that means parameters of a model which means parameters of a distribution, simple or complicated as may be. I don't know that any meaning can be assigned to the idea that "maximum likelihood is itself a distribution"; it's a method that produces certain results (or failure to converge...). Perhaps what you're getting at is that the result is, or should be, a fitted distribution.

Comment: I think you are right, fitted distribution seems like the correct term.

Comment: Using a natural (and accurate) analogy that parameters are to distributions as addresses are to houses, one might similarly ask whether the process of looking up somebody's address is merely finding their address or actually finding where their house is. We could press this analogy in some fruitful directions. For instance, although everything that needs to be known about a house's location is in the address, someone who is unfamiliar with that area of the world might learn nothing about the house's neighborhood from its address alone. This is one reason we use "known" distributions for MLE.

Comment: May be of some use for you to incorporate the idea of "conditional"? You may think of trying to estimate parameters for a _given_ (assumed) distribution (e.g., the mean assuming a normal population). Or maybe you are asking if, then, you get as result some sort of "distribution" for that parameter (e.g., a confidence interval for the mean)?

Comment: A maximum-likelihood estimate *has* a distribution - could that be what you read?

Comment: ML is (almost always) for parameters\*\*. But note that if you estimate the parameters of a distribution, you have also estimated the distribution itself (under the assumption of distribution family plus any additional assumptions). $ \quad $ \*\* even with ML there are infinite parametric cases, such as using $\hat F $ to estimate $F$ that correspond directly to estimating a distribution, so the distinction is sometimes not one.

Comment: @Scortchi: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85682/how-does-maximum-likelihood-estimation-have-an-approximate-normal-distribution

Answer (score 5):

The Maximum Likelihood Estimator is derived as the argmax of the joint density of the sample, viewed as a function of the parameters (i.e. of the likelihood). Hence, one cannot apply maximum likelihood estimation without previously specifying (or deriving) a joint density, and hence a distribution. After all, this is one of the criticisms that ML estimation has received -that it must specify a distribution -not necessarily one of the "known" ones, but a distribution nevertheless-, increasing the possibility for misspecification.

If one views a distribution with unknown parameters as a family of distributions, then at the end of the process, we get a *specifically parametrized* incarnation of this family, using the ML estimates of these unknown parameters.

Comment: After we perform MLE over this suspected distribution, we are left with a set of estimated parameters that are associated with this distribution?  If so, the answer to my question is "both."

Comment: It depends on how do you understand "new distribution". Before estimation, you had an abstract distribution with unknown parameters, one incarnation of which was "picked up" by the MLE. If that means "new" to you, fine by me.